# Add client-side library to Razor Class Library

Tags: blazor, razor-class-library

I am learning Blazor and I noticed it is a nice practice to create Razor Class Library where you are going to define majority of your components so you can use those either in client or server without too much issues. In different frameworks I've got used to include libraries as bootstrap in SASS form so I can use it in my components and I can easily adjust styles instead of editing resulting CSS. So I was thinking it would be good idea to include Bootstrap SASS into the Razor Class Library that is going to be later used in either server or client solutions however I do not see a dropdown or other way to add client side library into Razor Class Library. Is there a way around it or it has to be added only to the projects that is going to be referring it? This would be silly since I would have to duplicate the work to customize Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

To add statics assets such as js libraries or css to a Blazor components library add them in the *wwwroot* folder, this work the same way than Razor class libraries:

- [Create a Razor components class library with static assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-razor-components-class-library-with-static-assets)
- [Create an RCL with static assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-an-rcl-with-static-assets)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong...you can't choose 'Client-Side Library...' when you perform a right-click on the wwwroot folder like you can do in Blazor projects.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple console application, that can compile sass files to css with RCL support in Blazor WASM.

You can add your sass files into the `wwwroot` of RCL and write "_content/MyLibrary/sass.scss" in `@use` or `@import` at the Blazor Client. Watch mode also supported.

You can find the tool in github https://github.com/MONQDL/DartSassBuildWatcherTool.