# How do you include Bootstrap in Razor class library

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor, blazor, maui-blazor

I'd like to create a razor class library with several components and use that in various Blazor or MAUI Blazor projects. However, these projects have inconsistent Bootstrap versions, and I would like for this class library to have its own Bootstrap version, making it really self-contained.

How to self-contain a specific Bootstrap version withing my Razor class library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you can try to add the Package Reference into the Razor class library's csproj file according to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535773/how-to-add-tsconfig-to-razor-class-library-nuget-package), such as:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Twitter.Bootstrap" Version="3.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But you need to change the Razor class library to a nuget package. Because the RCL can't add `Client-Side Library` directly. And the boostrap's style files such as .js and .ccs file need be added in the wwwroot folder.

For more information, you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61352697/add-client-side-library-to-razor-class-library).